# Restrict access of web application other than localhost

Tags: java, jetty

I hv 3 java web-apps running in jetty and i want one of them to be accessed only through localhost. I dont want to write filter. Can it be done by modifying some jetty configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely simplest solution is to bind your server socket to localhost only. Setting `host` parameter of your connector to `localhost` should do the work. Note that this only works for localhost, it will make Jetty to listen only on loopback interface.

Answer (score 2):

#### Playing with Virtual Hosts

To do this by configuration, you could maybe use virtual hosts. From [the documentation](http://communitymapbuilder.org/display/JETTY/Virtual+hosts):

> Suppose also we have another webapp,
>   zzz.war. We want xxx.war to be
>   deployed as above, and zzz.war to be
>   deployed only from 777.888.888.111,
>   www.other.com, www.other.net and
>   www.other.org:
>
> ```
> <!-- webapp xxx.war -->
> <Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
>   <Set name="contextPath">/xxx</Set>
>   <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home"/>/webapps/xxx.war</Set>
>   <Set name="virtualHosts">
>     <Array type="java.lang.String">
>       <Item>333.444.555.666</Item>
>       <Item>127.0.0.1</Item>
>       <Item>www.blah.com</Item>
>       <Item>www.blah.net</Item>
>       <Item>www.blah.org</Item>
>     </Array>
>   </Set>
> </Configure>
>
> <!-- webapp zzz.war -->
> <Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
>   <Set name="contextPath">/zzz</Set>
>   <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home"/>/webapps/zzz.war</Set>
>   <Set name="virtualHosts">
>     <Array type="java.lang.String">
>       <Item>777.888.888.111</Item>
>       <Item>www.other.com</Item>
>       <Item>www.other.net</Item>
>       <Item>www.other.org</Item>
>     </Array>
>   </Set>
> </Configure>
> ```

So we could imagine having one webapp "deployed on" the local 127.0.0.1 IP address and the other deployed on names corresponding to the network IP address.

#### Playing with Connectors

Another option would be to define two connectors and to bind Jetty on *localhost only* for one of them. In your `jetty.xml`

```
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.Server">

    <!-- set up both connectors -->
    <Set name="connectors">
      <Array type="org.mortbay.jetty.Connector">
        <Item>
          <New  class="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <Set name="host"><SystemProperty name="jetty.host" default="localhost"/></Set>
            <Set name="port">8080</Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
            <Set name="Acceptors">1</Set>
            <Set name="name">connA</Set>
          </New>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <New id="connB" class="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <Set name="host"><SystemProperty name="jetty.host" default="0.0.0.0"/></Set>
            <Set name="port">9090</Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
            <Set name="Acceptors">1</Set>            
            <Set name="name">connB</Set>
          </New>
        </Item>
      </Array>
    </Set>

</Configure>
```

And then "assign" your webapp to the chosen connector. For example, in `contextA.xml`:

```
<Configure  class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">      
  <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home"/>/webapps/A</Set>
  <Set name="contextPath">/webappA</Set>
  <Set name="connectorNames">
    <Array type="String">
      <Item>connA</Item>
    </Array>
   </Set>
  ...
</Configure>
```

But as you can see, having different connectors implies listening on different ports (unless you have multiple NIC).

#### See Also

- [Configuring Connectors](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Configuring+Connectors)
- [How do I serve webapp A only from port A and webapp B only from port B?](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/How+to+serve+webbapp+A+from+portA+and+webapp+B+from+portB)
- [Using Virtual Hosts](http://communitymapbuilder.org/display/JETTY/Virtual+hosts)

Comment: Using vhosts seems dangerous (at least in general, jetty may have special code for localhost), as the vhost is just a string that is received from the http client.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a filter is the portable solution, and is easy to configure and use. It would have only a `request.getRequestURL()` to check whether it is `localhost`

[In this thread](http://www.javakb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/java-programmer/38314/Configuring-jetty-restricting-service-from-certain-IP) you can see an option to use apache as front end.

Another option is to simply have to instances of the servlet-container, running on different ports, and use a firewall to block one of the ports.

Comment: The link doesn't help anymore (well 4 years later).